# How to programmatically bind Hibernate Type for selected entity fields?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm looking a way to bind `Type` for specific entity fields during entity manager configuration phase. I need it to be able to apply extra "rules" to target entity field using external source without entity class changes.

So basically I'm trying to avoid hardcode `@Type` annotation way as below:

```
@Type(type = foo.package.MyType, parameters = {
    @Parameter(name = "fooProperty", value = "fooValue")
})
private String someField;
```

Instead I would like to set Type for `someField` while building model programmatically.

Comment: could you please explain more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way I've seen before.  It is a little low-level, so I suspect there is a cleaner way to do this.

This uses a custom `Persister` in Hibernate to allow us to substitute the type while the `SessionFactory` ( `EntityManagerFactory` ) is being created.

First, the `@Persister` annotation is used to declare the custom `Persister` :

```
@Entity
@Persister(impl = MyPersister.class)
public class EntityWithPersister {

    private String someField;
```

Then normally the custom persister should extend `SingleTableEntityPersister` in Hibernate.  If the entity is using a different `@Inheritance(strategy)`, then it may need to extend `JoinedSubclassEntityPersister` or `UnionSubclassEntityPersister` instead.

This offers the chance to change a type at the point of construction, for example:

```
public class MyPersister extends SingleTableEntityPersister {

    public MyPersister(PersistentClass persistentClass,
            EntityDataAccess cacheAccessStrategy,
            NaturalIdDataAccess naturalIdRegionAccessStrategy,
            PersisterCreationContext creationContext)
            throws HibernateException {
        super(modify(persistentClass), cacheAccessStrategy,
                naturalIdRegionAccessStrategy, creationContext);
    }

    private static PersistentClass modify(PersistentClass persistentClass) {
        SimpleValue value = (SimpleValue) persistentClass
                .getProperty("someField").getValue();
        value.setTypeName(MyType.class.getName());
        return persistentClass;
    }
}
```

If you need to access more of the context you are in, `creationContext.getSessionFactory()` is probably a good starting point.

Comment: Didn't know such an approach, thanks for sharing. However, while it improves the current situation of mine I still need to annotate each entity by hand with correct persister (for different inheritance strategy support).

Comment: I was able to override types w/o changing entity at all using this approach plus registering own PersisterClassResolver.